# Doskey macro with spaces in passed variable?

Tags: variables, macros, spaces

I am creating some common doskey commands I use on a regular basis.  I am trying to have multiple variables in the doskey macro and sometimes a variable will have spaces in it.  I have tried quoting the variable values but it won't work.  The only thing that does work is just adding more vars to the end of the macro string.

What I would like to do is:
     doskey keycmd=plink -l user -pw password $1 -batch $2
And then execute it as follows: c:> keycmd hostname "dir /p /users"

What doskey sees when executed though is: $1=hostname, $2="dir, and "dir isn't a command and /p and /users is completely dropped.

To get this to work I had to define it this way:
     doskey keycmd=plink -l user -pw password $1 -batch $2 $3 $4
And execute as follows: c:> keycmd hostname dir /p /users

Is there a way I can group "dir /p /users" into a single $2 variable?  For doskey variable parameters you only get 9, $1..$9.  Eventually I could run out on complicated commands. I tried single and double quotes to no avail...but single and/or double quotes seem to work everywhere else in Windows cmd command.

Is there a solution to this or am I just trying to do too much with doskey?

Answer (score 6):

This should do it. Tell the last var to be everything else

```
keycmd=echo plink -l user -pw password $1 -batch $*
```

Answer (score 2):

While you might have spaces in the last parameter (using `$*` as in [wild2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2117378/wild2010)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19081900/6309)), it is generally **not possible** to include parameters with spaces in a doskey command.

See [Using Doskey](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/u-doskey0.html):

> Unfortunately, although a parameter can be a long filename, it cannot include spaces, even if enclosed in inverted commas.
>   **If a filename includes spaces, it is necessary to **[use the 8.3 version of the name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)**. I know of no work around to this**.
>
> DosKey macros can also use `$*` which is termed a "global replaceable parameter".
>   This must be the last part of a macro and is replaced by whatever is on the command line that is not the macro name or assigned to numbered parameters.
>   If the above example was rewritten as:

```
DOSKEY D2F=DIR $1 $g $*
```

> then long filenames-with-spaces could be used as the final parameter - but the path name used as a substitute for `$1` still could not contain directory names with spaces.